# Function to check if a numbers sequence is increasing

Tags: javascript

I need to write a function that takes in a sequence of numbers and returns true if the sequence is increasing or false if it's not:

```
function isIncreasingSequence(numbers) {
  /**Check if numbers sequence is increasing
  * @param {number} numbers - a sequence of input numbers;
  * @return {boolean} - true if given sequence is increasing, false othrewise
  */
  let numArr = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  let truthArray = [];

  for (var num = 0; num < numArr.length; num++) {
    while (numArr[num + 1] !== undefined) {
      if (numArr[num] < numArr[num + 1]) {
        truthArray.push(true);
      } else {
        truthArray.push(false);
      }
      num++
    }
  }

  if (truthArray.includes(false)) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Some samples:

```
console.log(isIncreasingSequence(1,2,3,4)); //true
console.log(isIncreasingSequence(1,255,53,0)); //false
console.log(isIncreasingSequence(0, 0.2, 0.3, 1)); //true
```

I don't like this `while` loop nested inside of a `for` loop. Is there a better way to handle it?

Comment: Given your parameter name and the jsdoc, I had expected `numbers` to be an array, to be checked instead of the `numArr`/`arguments`. Which do you want?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the loop? It doesn't seem to do anything. You could replace the loop with just `var num = 0` before the while.

Comment: "if sequence is increasing" is ambiguous. I would add another kind of solution where you calculate the trend line of the values against the index in O(n) time and if the slope is +ve then the numbers are globally increasing, even if not always locally, e.g. I would class 1,2,3,5,4,6,7,8,9 as increasing by this definition.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## Implementation

- The current return statement has the form `if(condition) return !condition; else return condition;`. This can be simplified to `return !condition`, i.e. `return !truthArray.includes(false);`.
- The current implementation uses \$O(n^2)\$ runtime and memory, even though it is possible with \$O(n)\$ runtime and \$O(1)\$ memory:

  - The `while` loop can be exchanged for an `if` condition, or dropped entirely if there are no expected `undefined` entries in the input array (in that case, also remove the superfluous `num++`) by changing the `for` loops condition to `num < numArr.length - 1`.
  - There is no need to push every partial result into an array: If there is a mismatch, just return `false`. If there is no mismatch (i.e. you reach the end of the function), simply return `true`.
- The current implementation returns `false` for input `1, 2, 2, 3`. Is this intended?

## Cleaned up code

```
/**Check if numbers sequence is increasing
* @param {number} numbers - a sequence of input numbers, must be valid floating point values;
* @return {boolean} - true if given sequence is increasing, false otherwise
*/
function isIncreasingSequence(numbers) {
  let numArr = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);

  for (var num = 0; num < numArr.length - 1; num++) {
      if (numArr[num] >= numArr[num + 1] || Number.isNaN(numArr[num]) || Number.isNaN(numArr[num + 1])) {
          return false;
      }
  }

  return true;
}
```

> The condition `numArr[num] >= numArr[num + 1] || Number.isNaN(numArr[num]) || Number.isNaN(numArr[num + 1])` could be reduced to `!(numArr[num] < numArr[num + 1])`, but I chose the current condition because it makes the handling of `NaN` values more visible.
>
> NOTE: Arguments are not validated, call this function with non-`Number` arguments at your own risk!

Comment: "The current implementation returns false for input 1, 2, 2, 3. Is this intended?" In an increasing sequence, every subsequent element must be bigger than the earlier. You probably thought of non-decreasing sequence.

Comment: @Luke: I was just mentioning it, since it wasn't clear (to me, at least) from the description in the question if he meant a **strictly** increasing sequence or not (in some context it seems the "strictly" is implied, in others it isn't).

Comment: Note that this implementation checks most of the array's elements for `isNaN` twice.

Comment: @qntm: Read the note at the bottom, one could incorporate those `NaN` checks into the comparison itself (`x` compared to `NaN` is always `false`), so they would be implicit. That said, `!(x < y)` might seem to be the same as `x >= y` for someone not as deeply involved with floating point math, so I prefer the more explicit variant (YMMV of course). (Of course, one could reduce that to one check per element, even in the explicit case. Feel free to adjust to your needs.)

Comment: For the handling of `NaN` to be effective, you should change the condition to `isNaN(numArr[num + 1]) || numArr[num] >= numArr[num + 1]`, and use an early-return before the loop, in case `numArr[0]` is an `NaN`. This reduces the number of calls to the `isNaN` function by, at least, half. Also, without the change, you will be using the operator `>=` on `NaN`s. On the bit I gave you, I'm taking advantage of short-circuit evaluation, to skip `numArr[num] >= numArr[num + 1]` if `isNaN(numArr[num + 1])` is `true`.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel: If performance matters that much, use the condition from the box. I chose readability instead, and chose this specific representation because it confines the whole comparison logic into the same `if` statement (so it doesn't get scattered around). Also, I think short circuit evaluation works either way, unless encountering a `NaN` value is much more likely than encountering a non-increasing sequence. After all, comparison of `NaN` values is well defined, it will always return `false` if either operand is `NaN` (even `NaN === NaN` returns false!)..

Comment: I understand all that, but the code is still incorrect. The NaN handling is missing the point entirely. The reason to check for NaN is to be sure that the `>=` operator is comparing numbers. The way you have it set, is it the first thing to run, before any NaN validation. The validation is coming at the end, after the bit that matters (the `numArr[num] >= numArr[num + 1]`).

Comment: To illustrate better the problem, create this function: `function gte(a, b){ var result = a >= b; console.log(a, b, result); return result; }` and then replace `numArr[num] >= numArr[num + 1]` with `gte(numArr[num], numArr[num + 1])`. You will see that `gte` will run even if you call `isIncreasingSequence(NaN, NaN)`, when it shouldn't run at all. Also, you call `isNaN()` **twice** per element.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel: Comparison operators are well defined for `NaN` values: `x === NaN`, `NaN === x` or `NaN === NaN` are always defined to return `false` (same way for all other comparison operators). So the comparison (or the call `gte(NaN, NaN)`) are well defined and should run without exception (if it throws, your JS engine is buggy). Whether we check for `NaN` first or do the comparison first is irrelevant: Both are legal, well defined operations (we don't check for `NaN` because the comparison would be illegal, we check for `NaN` because we don't want `NaN` values in the sequence).

Comment: The problem is that the comparison is running for NaN, when it shouldn't. Your code should `return false` before running the comparison between the elements. First, you validate the data then you operate on it, Your code is operating on the data **before** validating the data. Have you tried to move the `gte(numArr[num], numArr[num + 1])` to the end of the `if`, and check the console?

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel: No, I'm not validating any data, just operating on it (and in this case, the order of operations doesn't matter). I'm not sure why you think I would be validating anything in there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68937/discussion-between-hoffmale-and-ismael-miguel).

Comment: @hoffmale Then why you check if you have any `NaN`? Just remove that.

Answer (score 17):

```
const isIncreasingSequence = (...numbers) =>
  numbers.every((number, i) => i === 0 || numbers[i - 1] < number)
```

Here we use rest parameters `...numbers` to treat the input arguments as an array. Then we use `Array.prototype.every` to examine each number in turn and check that it is greater than the previous entry in the array - or that it is the first entry in the array and hence has no previous entry. Note that `Array.prototype.every` will return as soon as it hits a counterexample, which saves time if the array is something like `[0, -56, 1, 2, ..., 9999, 10000]`.

If `NaN`s are a possibility, then the presence of a `NaN` in the array can be made an instant failure like so:

```
const isIncreasingSequence = (...numbers) =>
  numbers.every((number, i) => !Number.isNaN(number) && (i === 0 || numbers[i - 1] < number))
```

Note that each `number` is only checked for `isNaN` once. Note also that this check happens *before* the numerical comparison - numerical comparisons with `NaN` are hazardous because of their poorly-understood, non-obvious behaviour, and hence best avoided.

Comment: Although it's possible to force it all on one line, I honestly think code readability is improved by writing it out. Right now this is very hard to read quickly.

Comment: For readability, split it into `const lessThanLast = (num, idx, arr) => idx === 0 || num < arr[idx -1]` and `!numbers.some(Number.isNaN) && numbers.every(lessThanLast)`

Comment: Btw, is there a reason most answers here are still pre-ES6?

Comment: @DavidMulder I disagree, it's quite clear what the code does.

Answer (score 6):

Besides what Hoffmale already said in his answer, you can also use [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters). You have a parameter `numbers` which you are not even using, and you have to turn `arguments` into an array. With rest parameters the remaining arguments (which is all of them in this case) will already be an array.

Documentation comments should also be before the function, instead of inside it.

```
/**
 * Checks if number sequence is increasing
 * @param {Number} numbers - a sequence of input numbers
 * @return {Boolean} - true if given sequence is increasing, false otherwise
 */
function isIncreasingSequence(...numbers) {
  // Using Hoffmale's function
  for (var num = 0; num < numbers.length - 1; num++) {
    if (!(numbers[num] < numbers[num + 1])) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: This was indeed what I was about to write, an in addition to this, if you do have a non-array iterable use `Array.from` instead of `Array.prototype.slice.call`.

Comment: With your implementation the empty sequence and the sequence with one element are both increasing. The rest looks nice. I think you could possibly merge the if with the condition in the for loop. I am not quite sure which of the two ways is the better one.

Answer (score 5):

It has already been mentioned, but if you mean a "non decreasing" sequence as opposed to a strictly increasing sequence, you could use the following.

```
function isNonDecreasingSequence(numbers) {

    return numbers.slice().sort().toString() == numbers.toString();

}

console.log(isNonDecreasingSequence([1,2,3,4])); //true
console.log(isNonDecreasingSequence([1,255,53,0])); //false
console.log(isNonDecreasingSequence([0, 0.2, 0.3, 1])); //true
```

I personally feel that this is easier to read, but it is definitely an abuse of `toString()`.

Is it best practice?  Definitely not.  Is it a viable solution to a problem?  Possibly.

Answer (score 3):

**Nevermind:** I thought that the original code tries to skip over undefined values in array with this nested `while` loop, but turns out that this is just an awkward way to avoid going past the last element in array.

---

First off, it seems that the handling of `undefined` values in input is buggy:

```
isIncreasingSequence(1, 2, undefined, 3) // false
```

Shouldn't the `undefined` values be all skipped, returning `true` as a result?

Herein lies the main problem with this function. It's attempting to perform two distinct operations:

- skip undefined values
- check if numbers in array are sequential

As @kruga and @qntm have pointed out, it's easy to write a function that checks for the right ordering as long as the input only consists of numbers. Like so:

```
function isIncreasing(numbers) {
    return numbers.every((number, i) => i === 0 || numbers[i - 1] < number);
}
```

We could write a separate function that eliminates undefined values from our input array and then feed the result into order checking function. Well, we don't even need to write our own function for that, but could use [_.without](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#without):

```
function containsIncreasingNumbers(...maybeNumbers) {
    return isIncreasing(_.without(maybeNumbers, undefined));
}
```

Comment: The input is described as a "sequence of numbers" so I think we can safely assume there are no `undefined`s there.

Comment: Rather than pull in a third-party library, a better way to filter an array is to use what's already part of the language: `maybeNumbers.filter(n => n !== undefined)`.

Comment: Ah... I think I completely misunderstood what the OP code was trying to achieve with this `while (numArr[num + 1] !== undefined)` loop.

Answer (score 3):

```
function increasing(element, index, array) {
  return index > 0 ? element > array[index-1] : true
}

[1,2,3].every(increasing)
```

If you want something like [1,2,3,3] to return true as well, change the element > array[index-1] to >=.  I find this solution to be pretty readable.

Bonus ugly naming one-liner fun:

```
[1,2,3].every((e,i,a) => i > 0 ? e > a[i-1] : true)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use higher order functions, you can use [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```
return false !== numbers.reduce(function(accumulator, x) {
        return typeof accumulator === "number" &&
            typeof x === "number" &&
            accumulator < x && x;
    });
```

The reductor uses short-circuit logic to either return `false` or the currently inspected list item.

Comment: This still requires reducing over the entire list, even though you could stop at the first non-increasing adjacent elements.

Comment: This fails for the sequence `[0, 0]`, returning `true` when it should return `false`.

Comment: @qntm: I had to take a look at OP’s code again to spot that they appear to want to accept only strictly monotonic series. I didn't see that in any of the description text. Anyway, I changed the comparison operator.

Comment: @DavidFoerster this isn't about the definition of "increasing". It also fails for `[1, 0]`.

Comment: It's failing because your `return` statement is on a line by itself, returning `undefined`. All the accumulator logic is never being hit. Maybe you had different formatting locally?

Comment: @qntm: Ah, I haven't written much JS lately to remember the syntactic differences to other C-like languages and I tested my code as a one-liner that I only formatted for the sake of this answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your function is really easy to read and follow.
I, personally, hate the double-space indentation, but that's a preference.

But there are a few things that you can improve:

- You have absolutely no input validation.
  Verifying that you have more than 2 arguments is enough, and should be accomplished before running `Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);`.
  `Array.prototype.slice` is very slow for long arrays and array-like objects.
  The array-like object `arguments` has a `length` property, refering to how many arguments were provided.
  More ahead, you don't check if you are comparing numbers with strings, arrays, functions, regular expressions and what-not, which may lead to weird results.
- Your `for` loop is not optimal:

  - You are starting from index 0.
    If you store the previous number into a local variable, you can start your loop at 1. This is 1 less iteration, 1 less check and 1 less increment.
  - You keep reading the `numArr.length`.
    Consider storing this value in a local variable.
    Many will say that it doesn't matter much, and that this won't make much of a difference. Which is true, for smaller arrays.
- You are currently building a truthy table, and checking if there's any `false` in it.
  It is a lot easier if you simply `return false;` as soon as one of the conditions doesn't return `true`.
  This avoids forcing you to check every single item ahead needlessly, since you knew the result before finishing the loop.
- Aditionally, in contrast to what [@hoffmale](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/94458/hoffmale) suggests, do not use `if (numArr[num] >= numArr[num + 1] || isNaN(numArr[num]) || isNaN(numArr[num + 1]))`.
  This is why I say it:

  1. The comparisson is made first, before typechecking
  2. The current number is checked
  3. The next number is checked (on the next iteration, the "current number" will be the "next number").

  This makes it so that you are checking the same number twice.
  Doing the typechecking before comparing, and doing only to the current number will reduce the required checks by a large amount.

As such, you can write your function like this (keeping your style intact):

```
function isIncreasingSequence() {
  /**Check if numbers sequence is increasing
  * @param {number} numbers - a sequence of input numbers;
  * @return {boolean} - true if given sequence is increasing, false othrewise
  */
  var length = arguments.length;

  if(length < 2)
  {
    throw new TypeError('At least 2 arguments are required');
  }

  var numbers = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  var old = numbers[0];

  if(isNaN(old))
  {
    throw new TypeError('Invalid number on position 0');
  }
  for (var i = 1; i < length; i++)
  {
    if(isNaN(numbers[i] / 1))
    {
      throw new TypeError('Invalid number on position ' + i);
    }

    if(old > numbers[i])
    {
      return false;
    }
    old = numbers[i];
  }

  return true;
}
```

---

But still, the code isn't optimal.
Running the following code:

```
console.time('code');
for(var i = 1e4; i--; )isIncreasingSequence(0, 0.2, 0.3, 1);
console.timeEnd('code');
```

Shows that it still takes 4-5 milliseconds, on Google Chrome (on my pc), while [@Kruga](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/118747/kruga)'s ES6 answer is a lot faster (0.9-2 milliseconds).

Here are some improvements I've made, without any regards to keep the programming style integrity:

- Got rid of `Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);` and access the `arguments` object directly.
- Store the current number in a variable, reducing one more iteration and multiple accesses to the array, speeding up the code a lot.
- Start the loop at 2, instead of 0 or 1.

Here's how I've made it into:

```
function isIncreasingSequence() {
    /**Check if numbers sequence is increasing
    * @param {number} numbers - a sequence of input numbers;
    * @return {boolean} - true if given sequence is increasing, false othrewise
    */

    var length = arguments.length;
    if(length < 2)
    {
        throw new TypeError('At least 2 arguments are required');
    }

    var old = arguments[0] / 1;
    var current = arguments[1] / 1;

    if(isNaN(old))
    {
        throw new TypeError('Invalid number on position 0');
    }
    if(isNaN(current))
    {
        throw new TypeError('Invalid number on position 1');
    }

    if(old > current)
    {
        return false;
    }
    old = current;

    for (var i = 2; i < length; i++)
    {
        current = arguments[i] / 1;

        if(isNaN(current))
        {
            throw new TypeError('Invalid number on position ' + i);
        }

        if(old > current)
        {
            return false;
        }
        old = current;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Alternatively, you can use a do{...}while loop, like this, to dry the code:

```
function isIncreasingSequence() {
    /**Check if numbers sequence is increasing
    * @param {number} numbers - a sequence of input numbers;
    * @return {boolean} - true if given sequence is increasing, false othrewise
    */

    var length = arguments.length;
    if(length < 2)
    {
        throw new TypeError('At least 2 arguments are required');
    }

    var old = arguments[0] / 1;

    if(isNaN(old))
    {
        throw new TypeError('Invalid number on position 0');
    }

    var i = 1;
    var current;

    do
    {
        current = arguments[i] / 1;
        if(isNaN(current))
        {
            throw new TypeError('Invalid number on position ' + i);
        }

        if(old > current)
        {
            return false;
        }

        old = current;
    }
    while(++i < length);

    return true;
}
```

Another way to improve the performance is to use `old !== old` and `current !== current` instead of `isNaN(...)`, but the difference is neglectible.

This final version, using the do...while loop takes exactly the same time as [@Kruga](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/118747/kruga)'s ES6 answer.